# Using xsl:apply-templates with conditional filtering

Tags: xslt-1.0, apply-templates

This snippet works correctly:

```
<xsl:template match="msa:Group">
    <h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </h2>

    <xsl:variable name="iGroupId" select="@Id"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher[msa:GroupId=$iGroupId]">
            <xsl:sort select="msa:Name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

What I want to know is why I had to save `@Id` to a variable and use that in the xpath statement. This failed:

```
select="$PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher[msa:GroupId=@Id]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt:

```
select="$PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher[msa:GroupId=@Id]"
```

would select all `msa:Publisher` elements whose `msa:GroupId` child is equal to **their** `@Id` attribute.

In order to refer to the  `@Id` attribute of the **current** `msa:Group` element, you need to use the `current()` function:

```
select="$PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher[msa:GroupId=current()/@Id]"
```

Read the explanation in the specification:
https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#function-current

---

P.S Consider using a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to resolve cross-references.

Comment: Thanks. I have it working now with current(). I tried to get my head around the key concept you linked to but can’t directly see the benefits in this use case.